# Efficient method for storing strings? to

Tags: database

I need to store a whole lot  of strings in a file. The obvious problem popped up - when the strings are changed, they probably wont be the same length they used to be so I would need to fragment them or move things around or both which is expensive. I looked to another storage system that stores data that comes in various shapes and sizes - file systems.. but then i realized - empty space in the middle of a disk isn't a big deal while empty space in my file sort of is.

Everything I've thought of seems more like a band aid to the problem rather than a good solution. Are there any other systems like this that I can look for inspiration?

Comment: The string sizes would be mostly (I'm thinking up to 2/3 of them) ~30 characters long(file names) with the rest split between a few hundred characters(descriptions) and ~10 characters(names). The amount would be a few gigabytes at most, changes would occur rather rarely, maybe a few hundred per day. 

A few gigabytes.. didn't think of that before, seems like a rather insignificant problem now! heh.. still, I'd like to put at least some effort into optimizing this.

Comment: Obviously, somewhere in thinking about this question: 'how long is a piece of string' crossed my mind ;-/ It would help if you provide some estimates of, say, string size range, counts of the number of strings, frequency of amendment, total size, percentage of wasted space and anything else you have lying around that you think may be useful. Comments out of sequence 'cos i deleted and re-added this. Glad to have assisted.

Comment: right now I'm thinking to have a) index file with a big alignment size to avoid fragmentation when new things come b) align the data to 16 bytes, when a string gets changed I just make a new one and mark the old one as empty space c) When creating a new string, I first check if there is any big enough slot available from the deleted stuff or if not expand the file d) do periodic low priority shuffling around to keep the empty space within reasonable amounts. How's that sound?

Comment: google: 'efficient string store in a database' is an interesting starting point. There are lots of approaches. All have wasted space and efficiency trade-offs. I have no idea of the merits of any of them.

Comment: I get mostly stuff about how to set up an sql server.. I figured there might be widely used strategies like you see in other storage optimization goals and I just didn't know the names for them.

Comment: was just showing that there are lots of strategies for storing strings with various advantages and drawbacks.  I think your comment about it not being that significant an issue to your system is the most important. From your point of view, is an interesting problem, but not important in the 'scheme of things'.